# How to use multiprocessing to search pertifular folder in given directory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a directory with 260 folders.
What I want to do is divide 260 folders in to the list of 50 folders and loop through each list (of 50 folders) to find "specific" named folder in the sub folder of list of 50 folders.

my code:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

processes = []
def main():
    folder_name = "folder name"
    loc = r"given location"
    cx_list = get_all_dir(loc)
    pro = []
    for i in cx_list:
        x = Process(target=search_list, args=(folder_name, i))
        pro.append(x)

    global processes
    processes = pro

    for j in pro:
        j.start()

    for k in pro:
        k.join()

def search_list(text, l):
    for j in l:
        search_by_name(text,j)

def search_by_name(text, loc):
    folder={}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(loc, topdown=False):
        for name in dirs:
            n = name.lower()
            if n.find("archive") < 0 and n.find("$") <0 and n.find(text) >= 0:
                folder[name] = os.path.join(root, name)
    if folder:
        print(folder)
        return

def get_all_dir(loc):
    return "list of 50 sub directories in given location"


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

How do I use multiprocessing in such a way that if any one process find the folder, it should kill/terminate all other running processes because there is only one folder to find.

I tried it with this existing code, it is running properly but I want to stop all running processes when any process find "specific" folder. I don't want to wait till all processes are done.

Comment: do you need to use multiprocessing or have you tried [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) as it is pretty quick? Here is an example that  will find all the txt files in the documents folder and all of its subfolders: `glob.glob('**/*.txt', root_dir='/users/username/documents/', recursive=True)`

Comment: Or use `glob.iglob`, which is like `glob.glob` except instead of returning a (potentially very large) list, it returns an `iterator` that you can step through (i.e. it's more space efficient if you are dealing with a lot of files).

Answer (score -1):

in main:

```py
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
run = manager.Event()
run.set()
```

you pass run as argument for search_list

```py
x = Process(target=search_list, args=(folder_name, i, run))
```

and when you find it in your search function

```py
run.clear()
```

Comment: How do you propose to make to make this work in a multiprocessing environment?